# $merge doesn't return any output in mongodb pipeline

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a pipeline that looks like this :

```js
[
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "6295d353fccb2f44c3868f9a"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "...": "..."
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "...": "..."
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "collection",
      "on": "_id",
      "whenMatched": "replace"
    }
  }
]
```

The goal of the pipeline is to update some documents and to get the final document.

I implemented this pipeline using the go driver. And i observed that when the `$merge` stage is used, the pipeline returns an empty cursor. When i remove the `$merge` stage, the output is fine.

Does `$merge` prevent the pipeline from returning any result ? Can we change this behaviour ? Do I have to use a `find` after the pipeline ?

Comment: The $merge operator causes the pipeline to persist the results to "collection" serverside. It does not return documents to the client.

Comment: Alright thanks. So it's not possible.

Comment: Aargh. I wasted half a day on this. Had discovered the same thing. I get it but the documentation should make this explicit.